# When kubernetes pod releases its memory, does it return to the node?

Tags: kubernetes

I read [this article](https://home.robusta.dev/blog/kubernetes-memory-limit) about resource management in kubernetes. One of the important points there is this:

> memory is a non-compressible resource. Once you give a pod memory, you can only take it away by killing the pod.

What I am still having trouble with is what happened when the pod releases its memory, does it return to the node or still allocated to the pod?

For example, let's say I have a pod that is waiting for a job which comes at some interval. During the job, the memory consumption is high, but between jobs the memory consumption is low. So, when the memory consumption is low, does the memory is still allocated to the pod or it return to the resource pool of the node?